# Type mismatch resolving iterator Item to a pointer with an explicit lifetime

Tags: iterator, rust, lifetime

I'm trying to add functions to `Iterator` where the associated type `Item` is a reference to a struct with an explicit lifetime.

When I've wanted to modify the iterator state or return a new value I've had no problems, but when I attempt to return a new `Iterator` where `Item` is a reference with an explicit lifetime, the compiler complains.

### Example

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

/// First, an "Inner" struct to be contained in my custom iterator
pub struct Inner {
    text: String,
}

/// Then, the "CustomIterator" in question.  Notice that `Item` is `&'a Inner`.
pub struct CustomIterator<'a, I: Iterator<Item = &'a Inner>> {
    iter: I,
    _marker: PhantomData<&'a i8>,
}

/// Implementing Iterator for CustomIterator so as to define the `next()` function, as you do...
impl<'a, I: Iterator<Item = &'a Inner>> Iterator for CustomIterator<'a, I> {
    type Item = &'a Inner;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        println!("Custom next called");
        self.iter.next()
    }
}

/// Now, creating a custom trait definition called IterateMore that:
///   1. inherits Iterator
///   2. includes a default method called `more` which returns a `CustomIterator`
pub trait IterateMore<'a>: Iterator {
    type Item;
    fn more(self) -> CustomIterator<'a, Self>
    where
        Self: Sized;
}

/// Implementing `IterateMore` for an iterator of the specific type `Iterator<Item=&'a Inner>`
impl<'a, I: Iterator<Item = &'a Inner>> IterateMore<'a> for I
where
    I: Iterator,
{
    type Item = &'a Inner;
    fn more(self) -> CustomIterator<'a, Self>
    where
        Self: Sized,
    {
        CustomIterator {
            iter: self,
            _marker: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let inner = Inner {
        text: "Hello world".to_string(),
    };
    let inners = vec![&inner];
    inners.iter().more().next();
}
```

(See it on [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/CheeryIlliterateWidgeon))

### Error

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<Self as std::iter::Iterator>::Item == &'a Inner`
  --> src/main.rs:28:5
   |
28 | /     fn more(self) -> CustomIterator<'a, Self>
29 | |     where
30 | |         Self: Sized;
   | |____________________^ expected associated type, found reference
   |
   = note: expected type `<Self as std::iter::Iterator>::Item`
              found type `&'a Inner`
   = note: required by `CustomIterator`
```

Why is `Item` not being resolved here?  It is a bit frustrating as the compiler also complains if I try to set `&'a Inner` as the default `Item` type in the trait definition, saying:

```
error: associated type defaults are unstable (see issue #29661)
```

How could this be fixed or done differently?

Comment: [Working code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2efecb579b3429f2932d2b635bb3ccfa&version=stable). I can't elaborate on changes yet.

Answer (score 3):

It is unclear to me why you'd want to restrict the wrapped iterator to some custom type (given that you still have to write down the restriction every time you use the type, although that might change).  But perhaps your "real" `next` function does something funny.

- `PhantomData` doesn't seem to be necessary (anymore) to "use" the lifetime when it is used in a `where`-clause.
- `IterateMore` shouldn't have an `Item` associated type, given `Iterator` already has it.  (If you'd really need a new type pick a different name)
- As `IterateMore` uses the `CustomIterator` type it needs to repeat the requirements, in this case `Iterator<Item = &'a Inner>` (that is what the type mismatch error is about); this is not the same as saying `type Item = &'a Inner` in the trait definition.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=8ef51cf93da74b030c7cc3ee1b942c79&version=stable)

```
/// an "Inner" struct to be contained in my custom iterator
pub struct Inner {
    text: String,
}

pub struct CustomIterator<'a, I>
where
    I: Iterator<Item = &'a Inner>,
{
    iter: I,
}

impl<'a, I> Iterator for CustomIterator<'a, I>
where
    I: Iterator<Item = &'a Inner>,
{
    type Item = I::Item;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        println!("Custom next called");
        self.iter.next()
    }
}

pub trait IterateMore<'a>: Iterator<Item = &'a Inner> + Sized {
    fn more(self) -> CustomIterator<'a, Self>;
}

impl<'a, I> IterateMore<'a> for I
where
    I: Iterator<Item = &'a Inner>,
{
    fn more(self) -> CustomIterator<'a, Self> {
        CustomIterator { iter: self }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let inner = Inner {
        text: "Hello world".to_string(),
    };
    let inners = vec![inner];
    inners.iter().more().next();
}
```

You could also remove the type restrictions everywhere like this (and only add it back in the place you actually need/want it):

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1bc1a72f2236a1059b7a426fdc19108f&version=stable)

```
pub struct CustomIterator<I> {
    iter: I,
}

impl<I> Iterator for CustomIterator<I>
where
    I: Iterator,
{
    type Item = I::Item;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        println!("Custom next called");
        self.iter.next()
    }
}

pub trait IterateMore: Iterator + Sized {
    fn more(self) -> CustomIterator<Self>;
}

impl<I> IterateMore for I
where
    I: Iterator,
{
    fn more(self) -> CustomIterator<Self>
    {
        CustomIterator { iter: self }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let inners = vec!["Hello world".to_string()];
    inners.iter().more().next();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I see your point about Item.  Also, obliged for the generic example.  I've been relying on restrictive typing because the items for this iterator will only ever be a particular struct from a crate I don't own, and it doesn't have any traits I can parameterise.  I've toyed with the idea of sending a PR for that project which includes a trait for the struct in question that would contain a default definition of all its methods.  For the size of my project, I'm not sure if it's worth it.

Comment: Re `PhantomData`, it may be instructive to compare with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40484154/3650362), in which `'a` is used in the bound only as a lifetime parameter (`LT: ListTerm<'a>`) and is considered "unused". Here `'a` is used as part of an associated type (`I: Iterator<Item = &'a Inner>`) and is not considered unused (because the compiler can determine the variance of `CustomIterator` over `'a`).

Comment: (Although I agree that you don't need to parameterize by `'a` in this example.)