# Specify `Fn` trait bound on struct definition without fixing one of the `Fn` parameters

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I have a struct that contains a function object:

```
struct Foo<F> {
    func: F,
}
```

I want to add an `Fn` trait bound to the struct definition. The problem is: I do care about the first parameter (it has to be `i32`), but not the second one. What I actually want to write is something like this:

```
struct Foo<F> 
where
    ∃ P so that F: Fn(i32, P),
{
    func: F,
}
```

So in English: the type `F` has to be a function that takes two parameters, the first of which is an `i32` (and the second one can be anything). The syntax above is obviously not valid. I thought about three potential solutions:

1. The `for<>` syntax won't help here. Apart from the fact that it doesn't work for non-lifetime parameter yet, it is universal ("for all") and not existential ("there exists"). So that's out.
2. The other possibility is to add a type parameter to the struct. I already don't like that solution, because the parameter doesn't inherently belong to the struct.

   ```
   struct Foo<F, P> 
   where
       F: Fn(i32, P),
   {
       func: F,
   }
   ```

   But this doesn't work: the parameter `P` is not used, except in the `where` bound, so the compiler complains.

   This problem can be solved by adding a `PhantomData<P>` field, but this shouldn't be necessary and more importantly, users cannot use the struct constructor syntax easily anymore.
3. Lastly I tried this:

   ```
   struct Foo<F> 
   where
       F: Fn(i32, _),
   {
       func: F,
   }
   ```

   But this also doesn't work:

   ```
   error[E0121]: the type placeholder `_` is not allowed within types on item signatures
    --> src/main.rs:3:20
     |
   3 |         F: Fn(i32, _),
     |                    ^ not allowed in type signatures
   ```

**Is there a way to achieve what I want?**

---

*Side note*: Why do I want to have the trait bound on the struct already instead of just the `impl` blocks where it's important?

First, once the "implied trait bounds" RFC is implemented, this allows me to omit the duplicate trait bounds from all the `impl` blocks. Second, with this bound, it helps the compiler with its type inference. Consider this:

```
struct Foo<F, T> 
where
    F: Fn(T, _),
{
    data: T,
    F: F,
}
```

If the bound were possible (I tried it with the `PhantomData` "solution" above), the compiler can more easily infer the type of the closure's first argument. If the trait bounds would only be specified on impl blocks, the compiler has difficulties.

Comment: "I already don't like that solution, because the parameter doesn't inherently belong to the struct." Where did you get that `struct Foo<F, P>` means that `Foo` owns a `P`? As `Foo<SomeF, u32>` would be a different type from `Foo<SomeF, u64>` for example, this seems to be the appropriate syntax.

Comment: @mcarton [The `PhantomData` docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html) and the linked Nomicon section seem to imply that a type logically owns its type parameters. But yes, maybe that's not a good reason. Another reason why this just feels wrong to me: the `T` type parameter is already contained in the `F` type parameter. So the parameter `T` can't be chosen but is completely determined by `F`.

Comment: _"If the trait bounds would only be specified on impl blocks, the compiler has difficulties."_ — what difficulties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution #2 is the only way I know of to make this work with bounds on the struct. In my opinion making it work *without* bounds on the struct, as [Peter Hall suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50671920/3650362), is usually preferable because it puts the bounds only where they are truly meaningful, but if you find that onerous, an extra type parameter is your only option.

> 2. The other possibility is to add a type parameter to the struct. I already don't like that solution, because the parameter doesn't inherently belong to the struct.

The second parameter is necessary. The types of the arguments of a `Fn`-implementing type are *parameters of the `Fn` trait*, so in principle you could have both `impl Fn(i32, i32) for X` and `impl Fn(i32, String) for X`, just as you can have both `impl AsRef<i32> for X` and `impl AsRef<String> for X`.

In fact, if you don't look at it too hard, this is kind of how HRTBs already work: a function can implement `Fn(&'x i32)` for some *particular* lifetime `'x`, or it can implement `for<'a> Fn(&'a i32)`, which means there are an infinite number of possible `Fn` traits that it implements.

But you found the problem of adding a parameter for `P`: the parameter is unused.

> This problem can be solved by adding a `PhantomData<P>` field, but this shouldn't be necessary

[The compiler peers inside structs to determine the variance of their parameters.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40487993/3650362) In this case, suppose `P` is a reference type. Is it safe to pass a `Foo<_, &'static T>` to a function expecting a `Foo<_, &'a T>`? What about the other way around?

(As the linked answer states, constraints -- `where` clauses -- don't count for determining variance, which is why `PhantomData` is necessary here.)

But the `PhantomData` member *shouldn't* be `PhantomData<P>`, because `Foo<_, P>` doesn't contain a `P`. It contains a *function that takes a `P` as an argument*. Instead, you should use `PhantomData<fn(P)>`, which signals to the compiler that the variance of `Foo<F, P>` in `P` is the same as the variance of `fn(P)` -- a function (pointer) taking `P`. In other words, `Foo` is contravariant in `P`. To the human reader, this might seem redundant -- after all, we already have an `F` member, and `F` must be contravariant in `P`. But, well, the compiler isn't really smart enough to draw that conclusion, so you have to spell it out.

(See [the section of the Nomicon on subtyping](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html) for a more rigorous explanation of variance.)

Which brings me to your final objection:

> and more importantly, users cannot use the struct constructor syntax easily anymore.

Unfortunately, I can't think of a solution to this besides "write a nice constructor function". Perhaps a smarter compiler will one day lift this burden, but for now, `PhantomData` is what we have.

Answer (score 6):

Rather than put constraints on the struct, the simplest and best approach is to put the constraints on the implementation of all methods that will need to use the function:

```
struct Foo<F, T> {
    data: T,
    f: F,
}

impl<F, T> Foo<F, T> {
    fn call_f<P>(&self, arg: P)
    where
        T: Copy,
        F: Fn(T, P)
    {
        (self.f)(self.data, arg);
    }
}
```

> First, once the "implied trait bounds" RFC is implemented, this allows me to omit the duplicate trait bounds from all the impl blocks.

So it sounds like your main concern is about removing duplicate bounds. If that's the problem, you can try to group all the methods with the same bounds into a common `impl`, so you're still only ever write them once:

```
impl<F, T, P> Foo<F, T> 
where
    T: Copy,
    F: Fn(T, P),
{
    fn call_f(&self, arg: P) {
        (self.f)(self.data, arg);
    }
}
```

There's a little problem here, similar to the one you found yourself: `unconstrained type parameter: P`. However, now that we've got to here, you can solve it very simply by introducing a trait (you can name it better for your specific use case):

```
trait FIsAFunction<F, T, P> {
    fn call_f(&self, arg: P);
}

impl<F, T, P> FIsAFunction<F, T, P> for Foo<F, T> 
where
    T: Copy,
    F: Fn(T, P),
{
    fn call_f(&self, arg: P){
        (self.f)(self.data, arg);
    }
}
```

And users don't have to do anything weird<sup>[1]</sup>:

```
fn main() {
    fn callback(x: u32, y: &str) {
        println!("I was given {:?} and {:?}", x, y)
    }
    let foo = Foo { data: 1u32, f: callback };
    foo.call_f("hello!");
}
```

---

<sub>[1] They may have to `use` the trait. Which isn't *so* weird: you already have to do that with a lot of `std` stuff, like `std::io::Read` etc.</sub>