# How can I avoid PhantomData in this struct definition?

Tags: rust, traits

I have a trait that looks something like this:

```
trait Handler<C> {
    fn handle(&self, msg: &Message, connection: &mut C);
}
```

Instances are supposed to be chained like you would chain middlewares for HTTP handlers:

```
let handler = FirstHandler {
     next: SecondHandler {
         next: FinalHandler {},
     },
};
```

Each handler type can impose additional constraints on the type `C`:

```
trait ConnectionThatWorksWithFirstHandler {
    ...
}

struct FirstHandler<C: ConnectionThatWorksWithFirstHandler, H: Handler<C>> {
    next: H,
    _phantom: PhantomData<C>,
}
```

As you can see here, I need a `PhantomData<C>` to avoid error E0392 (`parameter C is never used`). However, PhantomData is semantically wrong because the handlers are not holding instances of `C`. This is ugly. For example, I manually have to provide the correct Sync/Send trait implementations:

```
unsafe impl<C: ConnectionThatWorksWithFirstHandler, H: Handler<C>> Send for Handler<C, H> where H: Send {}
unsafe impl<C: ConnectionThatWorksWithFirstHandler, H: Handler<C>> Sync for Handler<C, H> where H: Sync {}
```

The auto trait implementations would have an additional `where C: Send/Sync` bound which is not appropriate here.

Is there an alternative to PhantomData that allows me to encode the relation between `FirstHandler<C>` and `C` such that the Rust compiler is happy and I don't need more `unsafe` code?

**I'm not looking for associated types.** The handler trait and its implementors are defined in a library, and the concrete type for `C` is defined in the application consuming the library, so the concrete type `C` cannot be defined by the handlers' trait implementations.

The idea with this design is to allow the chain of handlers to accumulate all the trait bounds for `C` that are required in the handler chain, so that when I have the `handler` variable as shown in the second snippet, then the implied trait bound is `C: ConnectionThatWorksWithFirstHandler + ConnectionThatWorksWithSecondHandler + ConnectionThatWorksWithFinalHandler`.

Comment: [Specify `Fn` trait bound on struct definition without fixing one of the `Fn` parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50671177/specify-fn-trait-bound-on-struct-definition-without-fixing-one-of-the-fn-par) is a similar question that you may find useful to read

Comment: And [“parameter `'a` is never used” error when 'a is used in type parameter bound](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40484154/3650362) is also similar but with a lifetime parameter instead of a type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no need to enforce the constraints on the inner handler at the definition of the struct. You can delay them until you implement the `Handler` trait for `FirstHandler`.

```
trait Handler<C> {
    fn handle(&self, msg: &Message, connection: &mut C);
}

struct FirstHandler<H> {
    next: H
}

impl<C, H> Handler<C> for FirstHandler<H>
where
    H: Handler<C>,
    C: ConnectionThatWorksWithFirstHandler,
{
    fn handle(&self, msg: &Message, connection: &mut C) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Good point, thanks! It looks like I was fixated on keeping the trait bound `H: Handler<...>` on the struct definition.