# Unconstrained type parameter in trait impl for Fn

Tags: rust

I'm experimenting with impls of my own traits for closures; my trait has an associated type for the closure's output.

This works fine, with the associated type in `Fn`'s return position:

```
trait MyFn<Input> {
    type State;

    fn call(&self, state: &mut Self::State, input: Input);
}

impl<Input, State, F> MyFn<Input> for F where F: Fn(Input) -> State {
    type State = State;

    fn call(&self, state: &mut State, input: Input) {
        *state = self(input);
    }
}
```

But I can't get the same associated type to work in the `Fn`'s parameter position:

```
impl<Input, State, F> MyFn<Input> for F where F: Fn(&mut State, Input) {
    type State = State;

    fn call(&self, state: &mut State, input: Input) {
        self(state, input)
    }
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=dfbb1a258775d1ac2f92235cc2610cc7&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015

```
error[E0207]: the type parameter `State` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
  --> src/lib.rs:15:13
   |
15 | impl<Input, State, F> MyFn<Input> for F where F: Fn(&mut State, Input) {
   |             ^^^^^ unconstrained type parameter
```

Surely the type parameter `State` is constrained by the `where` predicate?

Comment: Separately from your question, Rust will not allow both of these blanket impls to exist. Even if you know that there is no type that qualifies for both impls, Rust doesn't know that such a type can't exist. So, once you solve this error, you'll have that one, which you won't be able to solve.

Comment: I didn't exactly want these two impls, but I did want something like `F: Fn(Input) -> State` and `for<'a> F: Fn(&'a [Input]) -> Vec<State>`, which falls into the same trap.

Comment: This reminds me of [Specify `Fn` trait bound on struct definition without fixing one of the `Fn` parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50671177/specify-fn-trait-bound-on-struct-definition-without-fixing-one-of-the-fn-par), which has the same problem with a struct definition. It doesn't work because argument types are parameters of `Fn`, not associated types -- there can be more than one `Fn` trait impl for some type.

Comment: I suspect the problem is related to variance. In Rust, variance is only about lifetimes, and it can be harder to think about than variance in inheritance-based subtyping.

Comment: In the second case `State` is in argument position, which means that any `F` that meets the requirements for this impl, could actually require a more general type (super-type) than specified. In the case of reference types, that means a shorter lifetime. I think the problem is that the borrow checker won't be able to figure out the lower bound on that lifetime. I'm not 100% certain of this though.