# How to make a generic of generic with trait?

Tags: rust

```
pub struct Triangle<T: Float + std::clone::Clone, V: vector::Vector<T>> {
    point1: V,
    point2: V,
    point3: V,
}
```

This chunck of code doesn't compile because T isn't used (Nevertheless, T is used later in a method)

I have tried this syntax

```rust
pub struct Triangle<V: vector::Vector<T: Float + std::clone::Clone>> {
    point1: V,
    point2: V,
    point3: V,
}
```

Error:

```
expected one of `!`, `(`, `+`, `,`, `::`, `<`, or `>`, found `:`

expected one of 7 possible tokens here
```

and this syntax

```rust
pub struct Triangle2<V> where V: vector::Vector<T> where T: Float {
    point1: V,
    point2: V,
    point3: V,
}
```

Error:

```
expected `where`, or `{` after struct name, found keyword `where`

expected `where`, or `{` after struct name
```

that doesn't work.

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: Could you also put the error message in the question?

Comment: Is [this code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=95454216b6d196d20da4af17499c6961) what you are after?

Comment: @so61pi Your solution  (triangle<T> {point : vector<T>}) works here but  triangle implements shape<T,V:vector<T>> and therefore it must have 2 generic parameters

Comment: Please **always** paste the ***complete*** error, not just a snippet of it.

Comment: Consider putting the bounds only on the method that needs them, as suggested by the answers to [Specify `Fn` trait bound on struct definition without fixing one of the `Fn` parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50671177/specify-fn-trait-bound-on-struct-definition-without-fixing-one-of-the-fn-par)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume your type `Vector` looks more or less like this.

```
pub trait Vector<T> {
    // Some functions
}
```

---

The solution is to declare multiple generic types and to list their type constraints individually: Type `V` must implement `Vector<T>` and type `T` in turn must implement `Float` and `Clone`.

```
pub struct Triangle<V, T>
where
    V: vector::Vector<T>,
    T: Float + Clone,
{
    point1: V,
    point2: V,
    point3: V,
    phantom: PhantomData<T>,
}
```

I'm using [std::marker::PhantomData](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html) to save the otherwise unused type information.

[Link to full working code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3f1fe422bb12e52c95358a28d888fcbb).