# Issue with lifetimes and type specifiers in struct

Tags: struct, rust, lifetime

Im wrestling with an interesting problem I found with lifetimes and type specifiers in a struct definition. What I'm trying to do is restrict all fields with type `S` - which is defined as `Into<Option<&str>>`, so that I can pass either an `Option` or `str` as a value for the field -  to a lifetime `'a` which is defined as the struct's lifetime. I'm using rustc version `1.58.1` in case it helps.

Here's what I got working so far:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct A<S>
where
    S: Into<Option<&'static str>>,
{
    my_field: S,
}

fn main() {
    let obj = A {
        my_field: "hello world",
    };
    println!("{obj:?}");
}
```

I want to remove the `'static` and restrict it to `'a`. For reference I want to create multiple fields with a type `S`. I tried two variants but unable to get it working with either. Hopefully someone is able to shed light on what I'm doing wrong.

##### Variant #1

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct A<'a, S>
where
    S: Into<Option<&'a str>>,
{
    my_field: S,
}
```

error:

```
error[E0392]: parameter `'a` is never used
  |
2 | struct A<'a, S>
  |          ^^ unused parameter
  |
  = help: consider removing `'a`, referring to it in a field, or using a marker such as `PhantomData
```

##### Variant #2

Trying `where for..` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40484544/10237506)

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct A<S>
where
    for<'a> S: Into<Option<&'a str>>,
{
    my_field: S,
}
```

error:

```
error: implementation of `From` is not general enough
   |
10 |     let obj = A {
   |               ^ implementation of `From` is not general enough
   |
   = note: `Option<&'0 str>` must implement `From<&str>`, for any lifetime `'0`...
   = note: ...but it actually implements `From<&'a str>`
```

Comment: It's probably not what you want to put the bounds on the struct. See [Should trait bounds be duplicated in struct and impl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49229332/should-trait-bounds-be-duplicated-in-struct-and-impl)

Comment: @ChayimFriedman yep, this is a good point. I can remove the bounds on the struct as I plan to use the struct as input to functions. But then I realized the problem there is I need to add generic type like `S1: Into<Option<&'static str>>, S2: ...` on each function that uses a struct like above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to follow the compiler's suggestion and use [`PhantomData`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html):

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct A<'a, S>
where
    S: Into<Option<&'a str>>,
{
    my_field: S,
    _marker: PhantomData<&'a ()>,
}
```

You can also have a constructor, for convience, so you don't have to repeat the `PhantomData`.

Another way is to lift the bound to the `impl`, because the rules are less strict there:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct A<S> {
    my_field: S,
}

impl<'a, S> A<S>
where
    S: Into<Option<&'a str>>
{
    fn new(s: S) -> Self {
        Self { my_field: s }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use the `PhantomData` suggestion because the plan is to expose the struct as `pub` to the client. The use case is to use the struct to build input data, and then pass into a function. But I like your other idea of restricting further down, like say an `impl`.

Answer (score 0):

I went with suggestion by [@Chayim Friedman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71119836/10237506) and decided to move the bounds to the impl (in this case a function) where the struct is passed in to. So the use case here is that the struct would be used to build input data with optional fields, then pass it into a function.

This solves my immediate issue, but again is slight issue with the need to repeat the bounds on each function where I pass in `input` to. So for now I am adding all the logic under the one function directly, to avoid duplicating the bounds in other places.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct InputStruct<S1, S2> {
    my_field: S1,
    another_field: S2,
}

fn do_something_with_struct<'a, S1: Into<Option<&'a str>>, S2: Into<Option<&'a str>>>(
    input: InputStruct<S1, S2>,
) {
    // do something with input data
    let opt1 = input.my_field.into();
    let opt2 = input.another_field.into();
}

fn main() {
    let obj = InputStruct {
        my_field: "hello world",
        another_field: None,
    };
    println!("{obj:?}");

    do_something_with_struct(obj);
}
```