# Why do I need to add trait bounds on impl blocks if I've already added them to another impl block?

Tags: generics, rust, traits, bounds

I have the following code:

```
use std::ops::Div;
use std::ops::Mul;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo<T> {
    bar: T,
}

impl<T> Foo<T>
where
    T: Div<Output = T> + Copy,
{
    fn new(bar: T) -> Foo<T> {
        let baz = Foo::baz(bar);
        Foo { bar: bar / baz }
    }
    fn baz(bar: T) -> T {
        unimplemented!();
    }
}

impl<T> Mul for Foo<T>
where
    T: Mul<Output = T>,
{
    type Output = Foo<T>;

    fn mul(self, other: Foo<T>) -> Foo<T> {
        Foo::new(self.bar * other.bar)
    }
}
```

However, the compiler complains:

```
error[E0277]: cannot divide `T` by `T`
  --> src/main.rs:29:9
   |
29 |         Foo::new(self.bar * other.bar)
   |         ^^^^^^^^ no implementation for `T / T`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::ops::Div` is not implemented for `T`
   = help: consider adding a `where T: std::ops::Div` bound
note: required by `<Foo<T>>::new`
  --> src/main.rs:13:5
   |
13 |     fn new(bar: T) -> Foo<T> {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0277]: the trait bound `T: std::marker::Copy` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:29:9
   |
29 |         Foo::new(self.bar * other.bar)
   |         ^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::marker::Copy` is not implemented for `T`
   |
   = help: consider adding a `where T: std::marker::Copy` bound
note: required by `<Foo<T>>::new`
  --> src/main.rs:13:5
   |
13 |     fn new(bar: T) -> Foo<T> {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This can be fixed with this modification:

```
impl<T> Mul for Foo<T>
where
    T: Mul<Output = T> + Div<Output = T> + Copy,
```

Why do I need to add `Div<Output = T>` and `Copy` to `Mul for Foo<T>`? Shouldn't `Foo<T>` already satisfy the bounds because of:

```
impl<T> Foo<T>
where
    T: Div<Output = T> + Copy,
```

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49231175/1233251

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each `impl` block is completely distinct from each other, including their trait bounds — the fact that one `impl` block has a constraint means nothing to the others.

In this case, your `impl` block for the trait `Mul` doesn't really *need* the `Div` trait, as it could construct the `Foo` directly:

```
impl<T> Mul for Foo<T>
where
    T: Mul<Output = T>,
{
    type Output = Foo<T>;

    fn mul(self, other: Foo<T>) -> Foo<T> {
        Foo { bar: self.bar * other.bar }
    }
}
```

It is only because you have chosen to call `Foo::new` (which has the `Div` and `Copy` requirements) that your original version of `Mul` will not compile. This is conceptually the same problem as this plain function which also doesn't need `Copy` or `Div`:

```
fn x<T>(a: T) -> Foo<T> {
    Foo::new(a)
}
```

---

Note that I've said "`impl` block", not "inherent `impl` block" or "trait `impl` block". You can have multiple inherent `impl` blocks with different bounds:

```
impl<T> Vec<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Vec<T> { /* ... */ }
}

impl<T> Vec<T>
where
    T: Clone,
{
    pub fn resize(&mut self, new_len: usize, value: T) { /* ... */ }
}
```

This allows a type to have functions that only apply when certain conditions are met.

See also:

- [Is it better to specify trait bound on the impl block or on the method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36142626/155423)
- [Should trait bounds be duplicated in struct and impl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49229332/155423)
- [Why does Rust require generic type declarations after the "impl" keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45473626/155423)