# How do I declare a struct that contains any kind of Deserializable/Serializable struct?

Tags: rust, serde

I am trying to declare a struct that contains another struct of any given type that can be `Deserialize` and `Serialize`.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Foo<T: Deserialize + Serialize> {
    pub data: T,
}
```

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8d2de8c05b2c3ba6848a4bb6c454aded).

For that, I have tried to use trait bounds, using traits such as `DeserializeOwned` or `Deserialize`. Both have failed at compilation time with the following errors:

```
error[E0283]: type annotations required: cannot resolve `T: serde::Deserialize<'de>`
 --> src/main.rs:9:28
  |
9 | #[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
  |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: required by `serde::Deserialize`
```

```
error[E0637]: `&` without an explicit lifetime name cannot be used here
  --> src/main.rs:10:19
   |
10 | pub struct Foo<T: Deserialize + Serialize> {
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^ explicit lifetime name needed here
```

I faced errors trying to add a lifetime since I am not using storing a reference but a value.

What is the most idiomatic way of declaring this type of struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution thanks to a member of the Rust Discord who referred me to the following Github [issue](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/964). The trick is not to use trait bounds but attribute bounds.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Foo<T> {
    #[serde(bound(
        serialize = "T: Serialize",
        deserialize = "T: Deserialize<'de>",
    ))]
    pub data: T,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just don't place the bounds on the type:

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize}; // 1.0.91

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Foo<T> {
    pub data: T,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Boo {
    pub a: i64,
}

fn main() {
    let data = Boo { a: 1 };
    let wrap = Foo { data };
    println!("{:?}", wrap);
}
```

Then, place the bounds on methods where you need that behavior:

```
fn use_it<T>(foo: Foo<T>)
where
    Foo<T>: Serialize,
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your suggestion on why it's preferable to add trait bounds on methods? I've certainly seen this before, for example with `Result` and the `Debug` trait which adds the `unwrap` method. At first glance, it seems that the code becomes less predictable to me.

Comment: @tehAnswer I didn’t state it was preferable, just that it’s an option. See a related questions on [struct vs impl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49229332/155423) and [impl vs method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36142626/155423) for deeper discussion.