# Syntax meaning for `impl<'a> Config<'a> {`

Tags: rust, lifetime

For the following code:

```
struct Config<'a> {
    query: &'a str,
    filename: &'a str,
    case_sensitive: bool,
}

impl<'a> Config<'a> {
    pub fn new(args: &'a [String]) -> Result<Config, &'static str> {
        if args.len() < 3 {
            return Err("not enough arguments");
        }

        let query = &args[1];
        let filename = &args[2];

        let case_sensitive = env::var("CASE_INSENSITIVE").is_err();

        Ok(Config {
            query,
            filename,
            case_sensitive,
        })
    }
}
```

Why `impl<'a> Config<'a> {` is required, rather than `impl Config<'a> {`?

What is the syntactic meaning of the first and second `'a`? I know `'a` is a lifetime annotation, but don't know why it's placed after both `impl` and `Config`. What does the first `'a` do and what does the second `'a` do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first `<'a>` declares a context which introduces variables which are universally quantified. In other words, `impl<'a> ...` means "implement for *any possible* lifetime `'a` ... ".

Once the variables are introduced, the second `'a` is the application of the variable to a type.

You can read the syntax `impl<'a> Config<'a>` as: "for *any possible* lifetime `'a` these methods are defined for `Config<'a>`".

In a more complex situation the context is where you can place constraints on the parameters. For lifetimes this is always an "outlives" relationship, for example `<'a, 'b: 'a`> ("for all lifetimes `'a` and `'b` where `'b` outlives `'a`"). For types, this could include both trait or lifetime bounds, e.g. `<'a, T: + Debug + 'a>` ("for all lifetimes, `'a` and all types `T`, where `T` implements `Debug` and does not outlive `'a`").

Answer (score 3):

*All generic lifetimes and types need to be declared somewhere.*

Try to compile your code to use `impl Config<'a>` and you'll get this error message:

```
error[E0261]: use of undeclared lifetime name `'a`
 --> src/lib.rs:9:13
  |
9 | impl Config<'a> {
  |             ^^ undeclared lifetime
```

Like type parameters, generic lifetime parameters such as the `'a` in `Config<'a>` need to be declared on every function, type definition or trait implementation that they are used. They do not even have to have exactly the same name as how the parameter was declared originally:

```rust
impl<'c> Config<'c> {
    ... // use 'c instead of 'a
}
```

See also:

- [What are the differences between specifying lifetime parameters on an impl or on a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31470146/1233251)
- The Rust Programming Language, [Section 1.1](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch10-01-syntax.html#in-method-definitions) on using generic data types in method definitions;
- The Rust Programming Language, [Section 10.2](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch10-02-traits.html#using-trait-bounds-to-conditionally-implement-methods) on using trait bounds to conditionally implement methods.