# Is it possible to mutate a struct's field inside a loop?

Tags: rust

Given is a struct which holds a struct with some byte code and an instruction pointer. It implements the pattern of fetch, decode, and execute:

```
use std::convert::TryFrom;

/// Trait for a virtual machine.
pub struct VirtualMachine {
    code: CodeMemory,
    instruction_pointer: usize,
}

impl VirtualMachine {
    pub fn new(byte_code: Vec<u8>) -> VirtualMachine {
        VirtualMachine {
            code: CodeMemory::new(byte_code),
            instruction_pointer: 0,
        }
    }

    /// Run a given program.
    pub fn run(&mut self) -> Result<(), &str> {
        loop {
            let opcode = self.fetch();

            if opcode.is_err() {
                return Err(opcode.unwrap_err());
            }

            let instruction = self.decode(opcode.unwrap());

            if instruction.is_err() {
                return Err("Bad opcode!");
            }

            let instruction = instruction.unwrap();

            if instruction == Instruction::Halt {
                return Ok(());
            }

            self.execute(instruction);
        }
    }

    fn fetch(&mut self) -> Result<u8, &str> {
        self.code.fetch(self.instruction_pointer)
    }

    fn decode(&mut self, opcode: u8) -> Result<Instruction, Error> {
        Instruction::try_from(opcode)
    }

    fn execute(&mut self, instruction: Instruction) {
        self.inc_instruction_pointer();

        match instruction {
            Instruction::Nop => (),
            Instruction::Halt => panic!("The opcode 'halt' should exit the loop before execute!"),
        }
    }

    fn inc_instruction_pointer(&mut self) {
        self.instruction_pointer += 1;
    }
}

struct CodeMemory {
    byte_code: Vec<u8>,
}

impl CodeMemory {
    fn new(byte_code: Vec<u8>) -> CodeMemory {
        CodeMemory { byte_code }
    }

    fn fetch(&self, index: usize) -> Result<u8, &str> {
        if index < self.byte_code.len() {
            Ok(self.byte_code[index])
        } else {
            Err("Index out of bounds!")
        }
    }

}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub enum Error {
    UnknownInstruction(u8),
    UnknownMnemonic(String),
}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, PartialEq)]
pub enum Instruction {
    Nop,
    // ...
    Halt,
}

impl TryFrom<u8> for Instruction {
    type Error = Error;

    fn try_from(original: u8) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        match original {
            0x01 => Ok(Instruction::Nop),
            0x0c => Ok(Instruction::Halt),
            n => Err(Error::UnknownInstruction(n)),
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler complains that:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/lib.rs:20:26
   |
18 |     pub fn run(&mut self) -> Result<(), &str> {
   |                - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
19 |         loop {
20 |             let opcode = self.fetch();
   |                          ^^^^ mutable borrow starts here in previous iteration of loop
...
23 |                 return Err(opcode.unwrap_err());
   |                        ------------------------ returning this value requires that `*self` is borrowed for `'1`

error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/lib.rs:26:31
   |
18 |     pub fn run(&mut self) -> Result<(), &str> {
   |                - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
19 |         loop {
20 |             let opcode = self.fetch();
   |                          ---- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
23 |                 return Err(opcode.unwrap_err());
   |                        ------------------------ returning this value requires that `*self` is borrowed for `'1`
...
26 |             let instruction = self.decode(opcode.unwrap());
   |                               ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here

error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/lib.rs:38:13
   |
18 |     pub fn run(&mut self) -> Result<(), &str> {
   |                - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
19 |         loop {
20 |             let opcode = self.fetch();
   |                          ---- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
23 |                 return Err(opcode.unwrap_err());
   |                        ------------------------ returning this value requires that `*self` is borrowed for `'1`
...
38 |             self.execute(instruction);
   |             ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
```

I think I understand the problem described by the compiler, but I can't find a solution or pattern how to implement this in Rust in a safe way. Is it possible to mutate a struct field inside a loop?

I'm using Rust 1.34 to use the `TryFrom` trait.

Comment: Sorry, I stripped to much from the first example. The whole project is a bit larger.

Comment: Removing things from the example is **good**; every word in [MCVE] is important, including "Minimal". For example, your current code has many enum variants that don't come into play. Taking your example and reducing it to the bare minimum that still reproduces the problem is one way that you show us that you've attempted to solve your own problem before asking it here.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [Cannot borrow as mutable more than once at a time in one code - but can in another very similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31067031/155423); [Linking the lifetimes of self and a reference in method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30273850/155423); [Cannot borrow `x` as mutable more than once at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31281155/155423).

Comment: Stripped the unnecessary enum variants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things preventing your code sample from compiling.

First, you have a number of methods declared as taking `&mut self` when they don't need to be.

- `VirtualMachine::fetch` only calls `CodeMemory::fetch` which does not require a mutable self.
- `VirtualMachine::decode` does not even access any of the fields of `VirtualMachine`

Secondly, as pointed out in [@fintella's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49352170/155423), `CodeMemory::fetch` returns a string slice as an error.

You don't specify a lifetime of this string slice so it is inferred to be the same as the lifetime of the `CodeMemory` instance, which in turn is tied back to the lifetime of the `VirtualMachine` instance.

The effect of this is that the lifetime of the immutable borrow taken when you call `fetch` lasts for the whole scope of the return value from `fetch` - in this case pretty much the whole of your loop.

In this case, the string slice you are returning as an error message is a string literal, which has static scope, so you can fix this by changing the definition of `CodeMemory::fetch` to:

```
fn fetch(&self, index: usize) -> Result<u8, &'static str> { /* ... */ }
```

and `VirtualMachine::fetch` to:

```
fn fetch(&self) -> Result<u8, &'static str> { /* ... */ }
```

After making those changes, it [compiles for me](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9df23505d0321acb269ab70bebba07e0&version=nightly).

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not want to be returning `Result<_, &str>` from any of your functions. If you use `Result<_, &'static str>` or `Result<_, String>` you should have much less fighting with the borrow checker. Even better would be to use a dedicated error type, but that is beyond the scope of this answer.

The reason that returning a `Result<_, &str>` is problematic is that it ends up tying the lifetime of the return value to the lifetime of `self`, which limits how you can use `self` during the lifetime of the result.

Comment: *Even better would be to use a dedicated error type* — OP is already using an `Error` type, so presumably they already understand the mechanics of doing so.

Comment: Good point. Of course that only helps with the functions that return that error type...